# Simplify inverse of function

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions, special-functions, inverse, inverse-function

This would be a noob question, but I need help simplifying the inverse of an expression

```
n = 1.45 ; \[Lambda] = 532; W = 0.5*10^-6; d = 2000; q = 1; p = 1;
f = Function[u, (BesselJ[p, (2 \[Pi] u/\[Lambda] (n - 1))])^2*(Sinc[
 W/\[Pi] (q - (2*p*\[Pi])/d)])^2]
g = InverseFunction[f]
```

I need a simplified version of g in terms of polynomials or other mathematical functions, which I can utilise in MS Excel.
I tried commands: Simplify, Expand, Refine...

```
Simplify[g]
```

But in all the cases, the following out

```
InverseFunction[Function[u, BesselJ[p, (2 \[Pi] u (n - 1))/\[Lambda]]^2 Sinc[(W (q - (2 p \[Pi])/d))/\[Pi]]^2]]
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Without specifying the range where the function is defined, the inverse is multivalued.

Comment: This function `f` is approximately just `(81 \[Pi]^2 Sinc[(1 - \[Pi]/1000)/(2000000 \[Pi])]^2 x^2)/113209600` or numerically `7.06157*10^-6 x^2` . The next series term is fourth order and the coefficient is a miniscule `-4.98658*10^-11 x^4` which is more than a few orders of magnitude smaller than the x^2 term. So if we go with that x^2 term alone, the inverse is approximately `(10640 Sqrt[y])/(9 \[Pi] Sinc[(1 - \[Pi]/1000)/(2000000 \[Pi])])` or numerically `376.313 Sqrt[y]` - The error is very low for small numbers, and reaches about 1% at y == 53 before blowing up after that.

Comment: Excel has the `BESSELJ` function and polynomial interpolation.  Seems like it could be done completely in Excel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

n = 145/100; λ = 532; W = 1/2*10^-6; d = 2000; q = 1; p = 1;
f[u_] = (BesselJ[p, (2 π u/λ (n - 1))])^2*(Sinc[
      W/π (q - (2*p*π)/d)])^2 // FullSimplify

(* BesselJ[1, (9 π u)/5320]^2 Sinc[(-1000 + π)/(2000000000 π)]^2 *)
```

Approximate `f` with

```
f2[u_] = Series[f[u], {u, 0, 4}] // Normal // Simplify

(* -((81 π^2 u^2 (-113209600 + 81 π^2 u^2) Sinc[(-1000 + π)/(
   2000000000 π)]^2)/12816413532160000) *)
```

The inverse of `f2` (approximate inverse of `f`) is

```
g = SolveValues[{f2[u] == y, u > 0, y > 0}, u, Reals] // FullSimplify
```

[image]

```
Show[
 ParametricPlot[Evaluate@{f[u], u}, {u, 0, 150},
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {f, u})],
 Plot[g[[1]], {y, 0, 0.14},
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed]]]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** For a variable `n`

```
Clear[n]

f3[n_, u_] = (BesselJ[p, (2 π u/λ (n - 1))])^2*(Sinc[
      W/π (q - (2*p*π)/d)])^2 // FullSimplify

(* BesselJ[1, 1/266 (-1 + n) π u]^2 Sinc[(-1000 + π)/
  (2000000000 π)]^2 *)
```

`f3` reduces to `f` for `n == 145/100`

```
f[u] == f3[145/100, u]

(* True *)

f4[n_, u_] = Assuming[n > 1,
  Series[f3[n, u], {u, 0, 4}] // Normal // Simplify]

(* ((-1 + n)^2 π^2 u^2 (283024 - (-1 + 
      n)^2 π^2 u^2) Sinc[(-1000 + π)/(
  2000000000 π)]^2)/80102584576 *)
```

`f4` reduces to `f2` for `n == 145/100`

```
f2[u] == f4[145/100, u] // Simplify

(* True *)
```

Use [`ToRadicals`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToRadicals.html) to convert the [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) expressions to algebraic expressions

```
g2[n_, y_] = 
 SolveValues[{f4[n, u] == y, u > 0, y > 0, n > 0}, u, Reals] // ToRadicals // 
  Simplify[#, n > 1] &
```

[image]

The second parts are consistent

```
g[[2]] === g2[145/100, y][[2]]

(* True *)
```

However, the first parts appear to have taken different branches

```
(g[[1]] // Normal) == (g2[145/100, y][[1]] // Normal)
```

[image]

Manually adjusting `g2[n, y][[1]]`

```
g3[n_, y_] = ConditionalExpression[
     ((266*Sqrt[2 - (2*Sqrt[-4*y + Sinc[(-1000 + Pi)/(2000000000*Pi)]^2])/
         Sinc[(-1000 + Pi)/(2000000000*Pi)]])/
         ((-1 + n)*Pi)), y > 0 && 4*y < Sinc[(-1000 + Pi)/(2000000000*Pi)]^2]
```

[image]

```
g[[1]] === g3[145/100, y]

(* True *)
```

Graphically verifying the inverses,

```
Show[
 ParametricPlot[
  Evaluate@
   Table[{f3[n, u], u}, {n, 13/10, 16/10, 1/10}],
  {u, 0, 150},
  PlotLabels ->
   (Placed[StringForm["n\[ThinSpace]=\[ThinSpace]``", #], Above] & /@
     Range[13/10, 16/10, 1/10]),
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {f, u})],
 Plot[
  Evaluate@
   Table[g3[n, y][[1]],
    {n, 13/10, 16/10, 1/10}],
  {y, 0, 0.25},
  PlotRange -> {0, 150},
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, Dashed]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, Thank you soo much!
Much appreciated

Comment: This worked nicely.
Another thing, the last one, is that I want n as a variable instead of specifying it (145/100).
The code works fine, but the issue is it gives the final output in Root[] form. I don't have much understanding of the Root function. Is there any way it can give output as ordinary functions which I will directly incorporate in excel workbook.

Comment: `λ = 532; W = 1/2*10^-6; d = 2000; q = 1; p = 1;`

`f[u_] = (BesselJ[p, (2 \[Pi] u/\[Lambda] (n - 1))])^2*(Sinc[
      W/\[Pi] (q - (2*p*\[Pi])/d)])^2 // FullSimplify;`

(*Approximate f with*)

`f2[u_] = Series[f[u], {u, 0, 4}] // Normal // Simplify;`

(*The inverse of f2 (approximate inverse of f) is*)

`g = SolveValues[{f2[u] == y, u > 0, 1.3 < n < 1.6, y > 0}, u, Reals] // 
  FullSimplify`

Comment: Thank you sooooo much. I appreciate that you kind of estimated that n (refractive index here) is between 1.3 and 1.6, which is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to implement the result in Excel, you might want to consider solving the problem completely in Excel.  Excel is certainly not the equivalent of *Mathematica* but it does have a lot of capabilities not appreciated enough.

For example, one can give names to cells so that formulas don't look like `C21*SIN(R27)+BESSELJ(A1,B1)`.  The Excel function `SOLVER` can do something very similar if not exactly what *Mathematica*'s `FindRoot` can do.

Here is a screen shot of how one might want to solve your question.

[image: Screen shot of Excel]

The formula in cell D2 is

```
=C2-(PI()^2*BESSELJ(2*(n-1)*PI()*x/lambda,p)^2*SIN((((-2*p*PI())/d + q)*W)/PI())^2)/(((-2*p*PI())/d + q)^2*W^2)
```

This is an example where $f(x)=0.003$ and the value of $x$ is determined to be 747.0876 (in cell C4).  (And certainly the answers from others here can be used for good starting values.)